# NodeJS ways to increase server performance in case of large number of connections and bulk of data

Tags: angularjs, node.js, real-time

I am in between building a web application for showing vehicles position in a map view, AngularJS as front end and Node.js as the server for real-time updating of the map. The events are coming from a middleware application to Node server, the server then has to apply some logic there to broadcast the data to the needed connected clients.

Coming to the question- the issue what I am currently facing is that, there comes around 20K vehicle data at a single time to the Node server, the Node server then has to decide to which connected clients should the data updated.This is achieving by looping each data against each connected client's map bounds.If the incoming data bounds are within the connected client's bounds that particular data will be emitted to that client. So this entire process will take more time if there have 1K clients and 20K data.

**Are there any ways to reduce this server overload by using any node techniques?**

What I have tried: I read through node clusters, but I think it deals with distributing connections across multiple workers. Is this a way for resolving my issue?

The sample code snippet is as follows:

Node server side logic

```
users // user array eg: array(userSocketId1,userSocketId2);

bounds //each user's bounds array eg:array({userSocketId1:boundsValue},{userSocketId2:boundsValue2});

app.post('/addObject',  (req, res) => {
 for (var k = 0; k < Object.keys(req.body).length; k++) {
  var point=[{'lat':req.body[k].lat,'lng':req.body[k].lng,'message':req.body[k].message,'id':req.body[k].id}];
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var userBounds  = bounds[users[i]];
    if(typeof userBounds!=='undefined'){
      var inbounds    = inBounds(point[0],userBounds); // check whether current vehicle's bounds within user's bounds
      var user        = users[i];
      if(inbounds){
      io.to(user).emit('updateMap', point); // send that vehicle data to one client say user
      }
    }
  }
}
res.send('Event received in Node Server');
});
```

Client-side logic for plotting vehicle info to map

```
 socket.on('updateMap', function(msg){
    L.marker([msg.lat, msg.lng]).addTo(map);
 });
```

Comment: Using sync code for huge piece of code is bad, you can easily use Promise in this. What is the schema of req.body? Is it a array-like object (like I suspect) or is there some other keys?

Comment: I would say that the way the system is designed is fundamentally wrong. Each request data coming in should in itself contain data showing to whom it should be updated.

Comment: @GiridharKarnik The data coming to the server is not based on user preference. The data is for all connected users, but the condition check is doing to check whether the user should update or not and it depends on each vehicle details within the vehicle array, the incoming data.

Comment: @DrakaSAN Thanks for the advice and answer provided. The request body will in the form of json array. So by doing the iteration process in Async by using Promise we can really solve the server load when there comes a huge amount of data for around 1k concurrent users?

Comment: Yes, concurrency will be improved, and server load should be too. But there is no other way to know that but making a load test

Comment: @DrakaSAN Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you can try is make the code asynchrnous, like using [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Without any library, this should work better:

```
app.post('/addObject',  (req, res) => {
    Promise.all(Object.keys(req.body).map((k) => {
        let point=[
            {
                'lat':req.body[k].lat,
                'lng':req.body[k].lng,
                'message':req.body[k].message,
                'id':req.body[k].id
            }
        ];

        Promise.all(users.map((user) => {
            let userBounds = bounds[user];
            if(typeof userBounds!=='undefined'){
                let inbounds = inBounds(point[0], userBounds); // check whether current vehicle's bounds within user's bounds
                if(inbounds){
                    io.to(user).emit('updateMap', point); // send that vehicle data to one client say user
                }
            }
        }));
    })).then(() => {
        res.send('Event received in Node Server');
    }).catch((error) => {
        res.send(error);
    });
});
```

Other advantages include not having to deal with indexes, easier to deal with errors.

It may not be enought, but you will not block each time you receive a request, and that is already a huge improvement.

Answer (score 1):

For existing architecture you need to do following things -

1. Use Cluster.
2. Implement your logic with Promise.

Or you need to update your architecture, you would need to store user position with socket id and user id. and you need to get all the socket id those falling in your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Here your performance player is Mongo
how?

If you are using multiple objects like

```
Customer=>{...} l times
Clients=>{...} m times
data=>{client_id:'something',...} n times
```

then you need looping each data and checks in it. which is equal to l * m  * n

here is the trick that save alot of things

```
Customer:{ 
     _id:Object('someid')  
    ,client:{ 
        _id:Object('someid'), 
         data:{ 
                 ...
                } 
             }
          }
```

It will decrease the looping factor and gives result in l * (no of clients inside)* (no of data inside).